# Emails could not be sent using AWS SES APIs. Error message with Status Code: 403

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

"Attempting to send an email through Amazon SES by using the AWS SDK for Java...
The email was not sent.
Error message: The security token included in the request is invalid. (Service: AmazonSimpleEmailService; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidClientTokenId; Request ID: af51a62a-1fdc-11e8-9ae1-d5b4f9a354b8)"

The statement above is a result from the sample program written in Java, which suppose to send an email using Amazon SES APIs.
Here is the example i found on Github:[AmazonSESSample](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/src/samples/AmazonSimpleEmailService/AmazonSESSample.java).

1. I have created account with AWS.
   2 I have also obtain my credentials: API_KEY and API_SECRETE

   3. I have place the credentials in aws folder under my user.home
   4. I have set my spending limit and have my service out of the sandbox environment.
   5. I have set my region which is US_WEST_2
   6. In a nutshell i have done everything i got from the documentation. 
      What is the cause of the 403 error is what i can not explain.
      Please any one with help to this issue.
      I really appreciate in advance.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

SES does not support using IAM User AccessKeys to send email. SES uses Amazon SES SMTP credentials.

> Sign in to the AWS Management Console and open the Amazon SES console
>   at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ses/.
>
> In the navigation pane, choose SMTP Settings.
>
> In the content pane, choose Create My SMTP Credentials.
>
> In the Create User for SMTP dialog box, you will see that an SMTP user
>   name has been filled in for you. You can accept this suggested user
>   name or enter a different one. To proceed, choose Create.
>
> Choose Show User SMTP Credentials. Your SMTP credentials will be
>   displayed on the screen; copy them and store them in a safe place. You
>   can also choose Download Credentials to download a file that contains
>   your credentials.

Here is a link to a document that explains the different type of credentials and how they are used with SES.

[Using Credentials With Amazon SES](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-credentials.html)

Here is a link to obtaining credentials:

[Obtaining Your Amazon SES SMTP Credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-credentials.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works exactly the way a wanted. Just that i am a bit confuse, not knowing the advantag  and disadvantage of the two: SES and SES SMTP. Anyway i have what i am looking for.

Comment: Amazon SES is the name of the Amazon service. SMTP (Simple Mail Transport Protocol) is a TCP/IP protocol for sending email.

Comment: Nonsese! All services, including SES, support IAM. IAM supports Access Keys. And there is an action ses:SendEmail. Obviously you can send Emails e.g. through the cli: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ses/send-email.html

Comment: @agoldev - This question is almost two years old. APIs, Interfaces and documentation change. If you have new information or a different opinion, post a new answer. At the time this question was asked, IAM Access Keys could not be used to send email with SES.

Comment: @JohnHanley I don't think the phrasing "IAM Access keys can be used to send emails" is at all correct. The question is, is there an API access to use send mail or not, and I would be almost sure that it exists since 2010.

Comment: @agoldev - At the time this question was asked, SES only supported SMTP credentials. If you have additional information, POST a new answer with details. I wrote a C++ SDK for AWS so I was deeply involved in the tiny features. That project began in 2008 and ran until 2016.

Comment: Something is still strange. I have a testscript, running again all regions.
I get the invalid token messages from all regions, except 
us-east-1, us-west-2 and eu-west-1